# How to strip() out a maximum of two white spaces from the front of a string

Tags: python, string

My string contains three white spaces and I would like to keep one. How then can I strip-out just the first two and leave one?

Example

```
>>> _str='   boy'
>>> _str.lstrip('  ')
'boy'
```

Ideal output:

```
' boy'
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `' ' + _str.lstrip(' ')`?

Comment: Perhaps you want `_str.replace('  ', '', 1)`?

Comment: Wouldn't work if there were more than three. The question implies that at most two white space should be deleted.

Comment: Just `_str[2:] if _str.startswith('  ') else _str`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, thank you very much. The first one works well, its enough.

Comment: There's something still wrong, my other string has only one white space, and non-of the solutions provided were able to remove the white space.

Comment: @Tiger1 your case isn't clear. Do you want to always strip two spaces? Always leave one space? Strip at most two spaces?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, at most two white spaces and some of my strings contain just one white space, hence I'm looking for a solution that could work on both one and two white spaces at once.

Comment: @Tiger1, you should edit your original question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very general solution, though not a one-liner:

```
def strip_n_chars(s, n, char):
    """Remove at most n of char from the start of s."""
    for _ in range(n):
        if s[0] == char:
            s = s[1:]
        else:
            break
    return s
```

Example usage:

```
>>> strip_n_chars("   foo", 2, " ")
' foo'
>>> strip_n_chars(" bar", 2, " ")
'bar'
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it does exactly what I wanted but not a one-liner.

Comment: @Tiger1 "too much coding"? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regular-expression approach:

```
import re

# 0, 1, or 2 spaces followed by a non-matched space
reg = re.compile("^([ ]{,2})(?= )")

def strip_spaces(s):
    """
    Return string with 0, 1, or 2 leading spaces removed
     (but leave one leading space)
    """
    return reg.sub("", s)
```

which then works like

```
strip_spaces("test")       # => "test"
strip_spaces(" test")      # => " test"
strip_spaces("  test")     # => " test"
strip_spaces("   test")    # => " test"
strip_spaces("    test")   # => "  test"
```

(if you really like one-liners, you can try

```
from functools import partial
import re

strip_spaces = partial(re.compile("^([ ]{,2})(?= )").sub, "")
```

**Edit:** (shrug) alright, I misunderstood what you wanted; use `"^([ ]{,2})"` instead (matches 0, 1, or 2 spaces), results in

```
strip_spaces("test")       # => "test"
strip_spaces(" test")      # => "test"
strip_spaces("  test")     # => "test"
strip_spaces("   test")    # => " test"
strip_spaces("    test")   # => "  test"
```

although not needing the look-ahead does away with most of the justification for a regular expression.

Comment: you solution doesn't work when the white space is just one. jonrsharpe solution works fine.